# Properties from vault

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I have a question in adding few properties in a list, which are stored in a vault and these vault details are configured in a config server. Can someone help on this. I have added the values as Hardcoded but that is not the right procedure.

```
case DELETE:
        ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
        //Hardecoded value
        list.add("SPECIALTOKEN");
        list.add("INTERNALTOKEN");
        list.add("MAILING");
        //Given the key which needs to bring the value from the vault and store here
        list.add("authentication.credentialMap");
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(apiRequest.getToken()) && ! list.contains(apiRequest.getToken())) {
        deleteToken(serviceResponse, apiResponse, apiRequest);
        return serviceResponse;
        }
        deleteJwtToken(serviceRequest, serviceResponse, apiResponse);
        break;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question, can you share what do you try to accomplish and what doesn't work?

Comment: I have the properties in vault as key value pair, now i want to add the key value "authentication.credentialMap" which needs to get the value as "INTERNALTOKEN" and needs to check with the apiRequest.getToken() which is coming from the Swagger where we are passing the value.

Comment: Is your "config server" a Spring Boot config server ? If yes then you can use properties injection so that it is available to your bean and then add that into list. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378420/java-spring-vault-not-reading-secret-from-hashicorp-vault